# How can use libsvm for multiclass pixel-based classification in matlab?

Tags: matlab, libsvm, surf, multiclass-classification

I'm working with libsvm and I must perform a multiclass pixel-based classification. I want to classify an image which contains Four classes. For training, I have extracted SURF dense features for each class and out it them in Data_Train.xlsx in which first column is the class and the rest is the SURF features. For test, I have extracted SURF dense features of the image ( that contain four classes at the same time).
My question is how to classify each pixel of this image and predict its class using Libsvm and then visualize the results.
This is my code

```
dirData = './Data';
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread(fullfile(dirData,'Data_Train.xlsx')) ;
% this instruction sort the data acording to the class label 
[sortedDataLabel, permIndex] = sortrows(ndata(:,1));
sortedData = ndata(permIndex,2:end);
features_sparse = sparse(sortedData);

model=svmtrain(sortedDataLabel,features_sparse,'-c 1 -g 0.07 -h 0'); 

predTest= svmpredict(model, featuresDense_test,'-b 1');
```